# Consumir uma API REST com NodeJS e persistir os dados em um banco de dados PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, api

Como Consumir API REST e salvar no banco de dados com NodeJS + PostgreSQL.
já montei todo o projeto, consigo dá um GET na API só não sei como salvar as informações no banco de dados.

**SEGUE O CÓDIGOS DA API QUE MONTEI**

**ROUTES.js**

```
const router = require('express-promise-router')();
const orderController = require('../controllers/order.controller');


//  Seleciona Data pelo Id: (GET): localhost:4000/api/data/:id
router.get('/data/:id', orderController.findDataById);


//  Lista todos os orders: (GET): localhost:5000/api/order
router.get('/orders', orderController.listAllOrders);

//  Lista pedido pelo Id: (GET): localhost:5000/api/order/:id
router.get('/order/:id', orderController.findOrderById);

// Rota responsável por criar um novo pedido: (POST): localhost:5000/api/order
router.post('/order', orderController.createOrder);


//  Atualiza pedido pelo Id: (PUT): localhost:5000/api/order/:id
router.put('/order/:id', orderController.updateOrderById);

//  Excluir pedido pelo Id: (DELETE): localhost:5000/api/order/:id
router.delete('/order/:id', orderController.deleteOrderById);

module.exports = router;
```

**INDEX.JS**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send({
    message: 'API Node.js + PostgreSQL',
    version: '1.0.0',
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**APP.JS**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

// ==> Rotas da API:
const index = require('./routes/index');
const productRoute = require('./routes/product.routes');
const orderRoute = require('./routes/order.routes');

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
//
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    //console.log("Acessou o Middleware!");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "OPTIONS,Accept,Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Header");
    app.use(cors());
    next();
});
//
app.use(express.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));

app.use(index);
app.use('/api/', productRoute);
app.use('/api/', orderRoute);

module.exports = app;
```

**SERVER.JS**

```
const app = require('./src/app');

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('API Executando na Porta: ', port);
});
```

Estou usando como exemplo para fazer um requisição externa a API jsonplaceholder.

Já pesquisei em vários lugares e não encontrei nada a respeito usando o NodeJS + PostgreSQL.

**FIZ DA SEGUINTE FORMA:**

**CONTROLLER.js:**

```
const db = require("../config/database");
const request = require('request');

    exports.findDataById = async (req, res) => {
          const { id, title } = req.body;
    
        const options = {
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/',
        };
    
          request(options, (error, response, body) => { 
    
              if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) { 
                 //obter dados do corpo ... por exemplo título
                  const data = JSON.parse(body);
                  const title = data.title || '';
    
                   ( async (err, done) => {
                      done();
                      // Handle connection errors
                      if(err) {
                          console.log(err);
                          return res.status(500).json({success: false, data: err});
                      }
                      // SQL Query > Insert Data
                      const { rows } = await db.query(
                      'INSERT INTO titles (id, title) values ($1, $2)', 
                      [id, title],
                      );
    
                        res.status(201).send({
                        message: 'Pedido Criado com Successo',
                        body: {
                          order: { id, title }
                          
                        },
                      });
                  });
              } 
          }
      ); 
      };
```

Mas não estou conseguindo gravar no banco e não estou  recebendo nenhum erro, estou usando o Insomnia para fazer os teste, faço as requisições e demora para responder.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3J3oykUzs8&list=PLPFhNx6dMDJrGREcnnI6uxv8Mmx6zUeUW

Comment: Agradeço pela indicação do video, mais eu não estou usando ORM. Já consigo trabalhar com NodeJS + Postgre. O projeto já está todo funcional, consigo consumir informações do banco com a API. Consigo fazer o CRUD com a API NodeJS no Postgre normalmente. O proximo passo do Projeto é: Consumir uma API Rest (externa) e Persistir (salvar) os dados em um banco Postgre

Comment: Tem algum erro que aparece? Verificou se dentro de `data` está de fato os dados da api requisitada? Poste as tentativas e o que está acontecendo de fato, que assim a gente possa entender melhor.

Comment: oi Vagner, não tem erro nenhum. Eu quero saber como salvar as informações que recebo da API REST no banco de dados Postgre

Comment: Crie uma entidade no seu projeto com as informações que deseja salvar, consulta API e instancie objetos com os dados consumidos, depois chame o repositório da sua entidade e salve essas informações. Isso te ajuda?

Comment: Oi Eduardo, você poderia exemplificar como eu faria isso. Usando esse endpoint de exemplo que cite8 na pergunta

Comment: @Eduardo Lopes atualizei a pergunta adicionando o que conseguir fazer. Mas não estou conseguindo gravar no banco de dados, porem não estou obtendo erro, qual será o mistério?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente você precisa criar uma entidade do seu modelo de negócios da API, por exemplo. Esta entidade ela representará o que a chamada a API terá de dados para você salvar no banco.

### Users.ts

```
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from 'uuid';

class User {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
  password: string;
  created_at: Date;

  constructor() {
    if (!this.id) {
      this.id = uuidV4();
    }
  }
}

export { User };
```

Após isto, você precisa criar um repository para você ter seus métodos que façam a inserção, busca, deleção na sua base de dados. Então, a camada do repository basicamente representa todos os métodos possíveis para sua API fazer delegações ao seu banco de dados. Use como base de exemplo, o `implements IUsersRepository` é apenas uma interface com os métodos que estão sendo implementados.
Como pode ver, esta é a sua camada na qual você tem métodos para salvar no seu banco, no seu exemplo, você teria um `create` parecido só que passando as informações que aquela sua API retorna.

### Repository.ts

```
import { getRepository, Repository } from "typeorm";

import { User } from "../../entities/User";
import { IUsersRepository, ICreateUserDTO } from "../IUsersRepository";

class UsersRepository implements IUsersRepository {
  private repository: Repository<User>;

  constructor() {
    this.repository = getRepository(User);
  }

  async create({ name, email, password }: ICreateUserDTO): Promise<void> {
    const user = this.repository.create({
      name,
      email,
      password,
    });

    await this.repository.save(user);
  }
}

export { UsersRepository };
```

Após a sua camada de repository, você precisa de um service, o service basicamente ele pode fazer lógicas da sua regra de negócio, por exemplo, não posso inserir um usuário com um e-mail que já exista na base de dados.
Como pode ver no código abaixo, após o `if`, olha quem estamos chamando, o nosso `repository` na qual ele que irá inserir na sua base de dados.

### Service.ts

```
import { IUsersRepository } from '../repositories/IUsersRepository';

interface IRequest {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

class CreateUserUseCase {
    constructor(private usersRepository: IUsersRepository) { }

    async execute({ name, email, password }: IRequest): Promise<void> {
        const userAlreadyExists = await this.usersRepository.findByEmail(email);

        if (userAlreadyExists) {
            throw new Error("User already exists");
        }

        return await this.usersRepository.create({ name, email, password });
    }
}

export { CreateUserUseCase };
```

E por "fim", teremos o nosso `controller`, que será ele que simplesmente irá fazer receber uma requisição e irá devolver uma resposta.
Agora pensa no seu caso, podemos simplesmente fazer uma requisição a um endpoint nesta cada, pensando da forma mais fácil possível, e enviarmos os dados através do nosso useCase (é o service), e depois que enviado ao service, ele irá enviar ao seu repository inserindo na sua base de dados.

### Controller.ts

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

import { CreateUserUseCase } from "../../useCases/CreateUserUseCase";

class CreateUserController {
    constructor(private createUserUseCase: CreateUserUseCase) { }

    async handle(request: Request, response: Response): Promise<Response> {
        try {
            const { name, email, password } = request.body;

            const user = await this.createUserUseCase.execute({ name, email, password });

            return response.status(200).json({ user });
        } catch (error) {
            return response.status(400).json({error: error.message});
        }
    }
}

export { CreateUserController };
```

Comment: Oi Vagner, vi que você fez usando o .ts eu estou começando com NodeJS será que dá pra fazer com Node? Só lembrando eu não estou usando nenhum ORM e estou usando o ASYNC/AWAIT

Comment: @LuizMiguel Primeiramente quero deixar claro que Node.js não é uma linguagem em si de programação, tu pode utilizar o JavaScript ou o TypeScript para construir sua API em cima do Node. A diferença entre usar TS e JS é questões de tipagens, interfaces e alguns conceitos de OOP. O exemplo acima é um esboço do que você pode tentar fazer. Utilizei um ORM, mas você pode usar um driver do banco, precisa criar os arquivos de configurações. Aqui no stackoverflow não é feito para darmos a resposta de cara, o importante é você correr atrás. Até que o seu caso, tem muitos, só procurar direito.

Comment: Sei que o NodeJS não é uma linguagem. O restante do projeto já está todo montado. Já consigo fazer requisição na API o que falta é salvar as informações que a API me retorna no banco de dados. Consigo fazer o CRUD no banco de dados Postgre com a API que construir sem problemas.

Comment: @LuizMiguel Se você consegue fazer um CRUD, basicamente no seu `fetch` tem o `R`, só falta você pegar o `data` que retorna desta API e enviar para o seu banco.

Comment: isso mesmo localmente consigo fazer o CRUD, só não estou sabendo salvar o JSON que vem de uma API externa. Atualizei a pergunta adicionando o restante dos códigos da minha API  que fiz no NodeJS

Comment: atualizei a pergunta adicionando o que conseguir fazer. Mas não estou conseguindo gravar no banco de dados, porem não estou obtendo erro, qual será o mistério?